# How can I forward information to another website and obtain its response in Perl?

Tags: perl, web-services

In a Perl script (with Ubuntu) I'd like to do something like

```
    use Blah;
    ...
    ...
    my $response = 
       &Blah::Fetch($URL, {'method'=>'POST', 'parameters' => \%params});
```

which I've written for convenience to look a lot like a Prototype.js ajax call, but obviously we're using Perl not Javascript, we're on a server not a browser, and the caller wants to block until we get an answer or timeout back from the remote server. In case of a server or timeout error, defined($response) should be false. If there's a way to fetch HTTP status that's nice, but it is enough to know the request failed. It should be able to do either GET or POST.

I know I can do this by using system and wget, but that's a kludge.

What is the best way to do this task in Perl?

Is there a Perl interface that is nice and tidy?

Comment: You may assume that the remote website does not require login or need anything, like cookies or state, that's not in the \%params.

Comment: It would also be nice if there were parse functions for the $response, such as extacting values from a JSON reply -- so that we don't have to munch about deciphering headers and whatnot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use HTTP::Request

```
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST); 
use LWP::UserAgent; 

$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new; 
$ua->timeout(3); 

my $req = (POST 'http://stackoverflow.com',  
["param1" => $var1, 
"param2" => $var2]); 

$response = $ua->request($req); 
$content = $response->content; 

exit;
```

For response elements, see more here: http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/libwww-perl/HTTP/Request.html

Answer (score 4):

The *de facto* methods are with [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.834/lib/LWP.pm) and [WWW:Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/) to pass on the request. These libraries are often included in Perl bundles, but otherwise are available via [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/). [CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI.pm/) is the most basic module for handling most simple web requests.

Tutorials for both are common, try http://perl.com/ , http://PerlMonks.org/ http://perldoc.perl.org/ amongst others. LWP also offers LWP::Simple if your needs are basic.